# Is there a way to make the size of uneditable textarea bigger (java)?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout, jtextarea

Hello I've been working on making a library system and here in this textarea i have to display the books by search so It needs to be able to fit somewhat 3 books before the user has to scroll to read the rest of the results, I'm aware that by using grid layout all the spots are going to be distibuted evenly, can someone help me and tell me how i can make this text area bigger?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tARJu.png]

here's my code
And my text area is in panel P[6] if you want to understand where the problem is

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    JLabel NewBook;
    JLabel ADD;
    JTextField ISBNin,Titlein,Authorin,Yearin,Editionin;
    JButton Clear;
    JButton Insert;
    JLabel []EmptyLabel;
    JPanel []P;
    JSeparator J;
    JLabel SearchBook;
    JRadioButton ISBNRB,TitleRB,AuthorRB,YearRB;
    ButtonGroup radioGroup;
    JTextField SearchBy;
    JButton Find;
    JTextArea SearchTextArea;
    int []s;
    Font NBF=new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,20);
    public MainFrame() {
        super("Library System");
        setLayout(new GridLayout(22,1,1,1));
        NewBook=new JLabel("  NEW BOOK");
        NewBook.setFont(NBF);
        NewBook.setForeground(Color.RED);
        add(NewBook);
        ADD=new JLabel(" ISBN                                           Title                                        Author                                       Published Year                       Edition");
        ISBNin=new JTextField(15);
        Titlein=new JTextField(15);
        Authorin=new JTextField(15);
        Yearin=new JTextField(15);
        Editionin=new JTextField(15);
        P=new JPanel[10];
        P[0]=new JPanel();
        P[0].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        P[0].add(ADD);
        add(P[0]);
        P[1]=new JPanel();
        P[1].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
        P[1].add(ISBNin);
        P[1].add(Titlein);
        P[1].add(Authorin);
        P[1].add(Yearin);
        P[1].add(Editionin);
        add(P[1]);
        EmptyLabel=new JLabel[20];
        Insert=new JButton("Insert");
        Clear=new JButton("Clear");
        Clear.setHorizontalAlignment(JButton.CENTER);
        P[2]=new JPanel();
        P[2].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,10));
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            EmptyLabel[i]=new JLabel("");
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            P[2].add(EmptyLabel[i]);
        P[2].setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        P[2].add(Insert);
        P[2].add(Clear);
        for(int i=4;i<8;i++)
            P[2].add(EmptyLabel[i]);
        add(P[2]);
        J=new JSeparator();
        add(J);
        SearchBook=new JLabel("SEARCH BY");
        SearchBook.setFont(NBF);
        SearchBook.setForeground(Color.RED);
        P[3]=new JPanel();
        P[3].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,5,5));
        P[3].add(SearchBook);
        add(SearchBook);
        ISBNRB=new JRadioButton("ISBN",true);
        TitleRB=new JRadioButton("Title",false);
        YearRB=new JRadioButton("Published",false);
        AuthorRB=new JRadioButton("Author",false);
        P[4]=new JPanel();
        P[4].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
        radioGroup=new ButtonGroup();
        radioGroup.add(ISBNRB);
        radioGroup.add(TitleRB);
        radioGroup.add(AuthorRB);
        radioGroup.add(YearRB);
        P[4].add(ISBNRB);
        P[4].add(TitleRB);
        P[4].add(AuthorRB);
        P[4].add(YearRB);
        add(P[4]);
        SearchBy=new JTextField(21);
        Find=new JButton("Find");
        Find.setSize(20, 100);
        P[5]=new JPanel();
        P[5].setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4,5,1));
        P[5].add(Find);
        P[5].add(SearchBy);
        for(int i=8;i<11;i++)
            P[5].add(EmptyLabel[i]);
        add(P[5]);
        P[6]=new JPanel();
        P[6].setLayout(new GridLayout());
        SearchTextArea=new JTextArea(" ISBN                                          Title                                        Author                                       Published Year                       Edition\nISBN                                          Title                                        Author                                       Published Year                       Edition",500,580);
        SearchTextArea.setEditable(false);
        P[6].add(new JScrollPane(SearchTextArea));
        Dimension D=new Dimension();
        D.setSize(200, 580);
        P[6].setPreferredSize(D);
        add(P[6]);
        setSize( 780, 580 );
        setResizable(false);
    }
    public static void main( String[] args )
    { 
    MainFrame MF = new MainFrame(); 
    MF.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     // set frame size
    MF.setVisible( true ); // display frame
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Any text book or tutorial I've ever seen follows this Java convention. Learn by example. 2) Read the JTextArea API. You can pass parameters to define the default number of rows for the text area. 3) Don't use a text area. I would suggest a `JTable` would be a better component to display your book information. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). If you really want a JTextAre, the tutorial also has a section on how to use a text area.

Comment: *I'm aware that by using grid layout all the spots are going to be distibuted evenly,* - then you may also need to nest panels using different layout managers to achieve your desired layout. Again, the tutorial has examples.

Comment: Wow. 8 grid layouts. Learn other layouts. The grid layout has very limited uses. Also note that the numbers at the end of the text area constructors are rows and columns, not pixels and that most code (including this) should not be setting sizes or preferred sizes.